# How to check for corrupted raster data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, raster, multi-band

I am working with thousands of tiled (2km x 2km) 4-band NAIP images.  When I diced the images in Erdas, the program corrupted many of the tiles.  The screenshot shows an example of one of the corrupted rasters. You can see there is a small strip of actual pixel values at the top that range from 0 - 255. It is likely that there could be a strip on any of the sides of the image.  The larger black area contains all 0 values.

My attempts to programmatically scan the tiles for a maximum pixel value of 0 or a unique pixel count of 0 failed due to the small area of legitimate pixel values.  This is a simplified approach I have been using:

```
import arcpy

# input raster data is 8-bit unsigned integer with 4 bands (CIR)
raster = r'D:\temp\4310605_ne_4_2.tif'

p = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(raster, "MAXIMUM")

if p == 0:
     print "there is a problem"
```

What fast and efficient method can I use for checking 4-band tiff files for these corrupted areas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace point coordinates below by raster extent centre point coordinates

```
    p=arcpy.Point()
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(pntFile,("SHAPE@XY",theFLD)) as rows:
            for row in rows:
                    XY=row[0]
                    p.X,p.Y=XY
                    myArray = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(raster,p,1,1,-9999)
                    row[1]=myArray[0,0]
                    rows.updateRow(row)
                    arcpy.SetProgressorPosition()
            del row,rows
```

and if myArray[0,0]=0 there is 99% chance that there is a problem

Comment: You could throw in a dozen or so random points in the valid extent for surety. I would go with GDAL and read a few lines then check to see if they're all 0, how do you feel about a GDAL solution Aaron?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Interesting thoughts, a GDAL approach would be good too.

Comment: Thanks FelixIP.  The ideas in your script work great.  I tailored your script to meet my specific needs and included it as an answer.  I overlooked using numpy arrays for this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Building on FelixIP's answer, the following method checks for 1) zero values in a 200x200m area located at the center of the image and 2) corrupt rasters that will not read.  The bad files are added to one of two lists based on the problem.  Efficiency is good, with the script scanning ~2 tiles/sec.

---

```
import arcpy, os, numpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\temp\tiles'

rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

counter = 1
length = len(rasters)

badTiffs = []
corruptTiffs = []

for ras in rasters:
    try:
        r = arcpy.sa.Raster(ras)

        lowerLeft = arcpy.Point(r.extent.XMin + 820,r.extent.YMin + 820)

        myArray = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(ras,lowerLeft,200,200)

        if numpy.max(myArray) == 0:
            badTiffs.append(ras)

        print "%s of %s rasters processed" % (counter, length)

    except RuntimeError:
        corruptTiffs.append(ras)

    counter = counter + 1

del counter
```

Comment: Glad it works. Also note that r=arcpy.Raster(ras) will work as well, i.e. without spatial analyst. I've used for SA-free rasters(s) sampling tool, felt good